# segmentation error searching through binary tree

Tags: c, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I am receiving a segmentation fault while searching through a binary tree for a match. It does not give me a segmentation fault if a match is found but if it does not find anything it isn't  finishing properly. Could someone point me in the right direction? What am i doing wrong.

```
void search() {
    char temp,temp1[15];
    struct node *s=root;
    int i=0;

    do{
        printf("Enter Name To Be Searched\n");
        scanf("%s",temp1);
        getchar();
        i=0;
        s=root;
        while(s!=NULL && i==0){
            if(strcmp(s->data,temp1)< 0)
                s=s->right;
            if(strcmp(s->data,temp1)>0)
                s=s->left;
            if(strcmp(s->data,temp1)==0)
                i=1;
        }
        if(i==0)
            printf("Element Not Found\n");
        else
            printf("Element Found\n");
        printf("Enter More Elements[Y/N]:\n");
        temp=getchar();
        printf("%c", temp);
    }while(temp=='y');
}
```

Comment: "It does not give me a segmentation fault if a match is found" Well that eliminates several possible reasons for your fault. Did you run this in a debugger before coming here with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You change s and then compare it again in the next if statement. Also think about if something is not bigger then zero neither smaller, then it must be equal.

```
while (s!=NULL) {
    const int cmp = strcmp(s->data,temp1);
    if (cmp < 0) 
        s = s->right;
    else if (cmp > 0)
        s = s->left;
    else {
        i = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Try that.

Comment: Perhaps expand on this theme and stop calling the same function unnecessarily. There should only be one `strcmp()` in that loop and its result should be *retained* for evaluations therein. (and +1)

Comment: @fonZ No, I mean the two calls to the same proc with the same parameters *within* that loop are not needed. Call it once, saving the result in a temp, and run your if-else-if-else logic over the temp; not another call to `strcmp()`. Btw, the optimizer will likely do this anyway if it has any brains, but the code should do it regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your child node pointers are not null if there are no child nodes